# Why does my object inherit attributes but not have its own?

Tags: python, sqlite, oop, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

My goal is to transition from pure SQLite to SQLAlchemy. The project is an online shop using Bootstrap and Flask. [Current version](https://app.micaelmuniz.com/shop/) works satisfactorily without SQLAlchemy.

Model `Product` contains classes such as `Price` and uses other models like `Review` (which consists of `Review` and `Grade` classes). `BaseProduct` class inherits from `db.Model` in Flask-SQLAlchemy and only holds attributes that directly correspond to database fields (mirrors database table). I require additional attributes for the product so created the `Product` class (which inherits from `BaseProduct`). It introduces attributes not present in database, including `reviews` (retrieved data), `grade` (calculated using reviews), `price` (an object) and a `test` attribute.

When using `Product.get_product_by_id(1)` it returns `Product` instance as expected (class 'models.product.Product'). However, using `dir` only attributes from `db.Models`, `BaseProduct` and `Product` methods are listed, but not `Product`'s attributes. These attributes are defined in constructor `__init__` (but are not displayed).

```
products[0].test
          ^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Product' object has no attribute 'test'
```

```
products[0].reviews
          ^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Product' object has no attribute 'reviews'
```

database.py:

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

models/product.py:

```py
import json
from models.review import Review, Grade
from database import db


# TODO: use pydantic to validate data
class Price:
    def __init__(self, new: float, old: float):
        self.new = new
        self.old = old

    def __str__(self):
        return self.label_price(self.new)

    def __float__(self):
        return self.new

    @staticmethod
    def label_price(price: float) -> str:
        return "{:.2f}".format(price).replace('.', ',')


class BaseProduct(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    price_current = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    price_old = db.Column(db.Float, nullable=False)
    category = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('category.id'), nullable=False)
    promotion = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable=False)
    image_thumb_url = db.Column(db.String(200), nullable=False)
    description = db.Column(db.String(500), nullable=False)
    color = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
    additional_info = db.Column(db.JSON, nullable=True)
    extra_images = db.Column(db.JSON, nullable=True)

    def commit(self) -> int:
        db.session.add(self)
        db.session.commit()
        return self.id

    def delete(self):
        db.session.delete(self)
        db.session.commit()


class Product(BaseProduct):

    def __init__(self, name: str, price_current: float, price_old: float, category: int, promotion: bool,
                 image_thumb_url: str, description: str, color: str, additional_info: dict, extra_images: dict):
        super().__init__(
            name=name,
            price_current=price_current,
            price_old=price_old,
            category=category,
            promotion=promotion,
            image_thumb_url=image_thumb_url,
            description=description,
            color=color,
            additional_info=additional_info,
            extra_images=extra_images
        )
        self.test = 'test'
        self.price = Price(price_current, price_old)
        self.color = color if color else self.detect_color(self.image_thumb_url)
        self.reviews = Review.get_reviews_by_product_id(self.id)
        self.grade = Grade.calcule_grade_from_reviews(self.reviews)


    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name} - {self.price}"

    @staticmethod
    def detect_color(img_url: str) -> str:
        dominant_color = 'Neutro'
        return dominant_color

    @classmethod
    def get_all_products(cls) -> list['Product']:
        return cls.query.all()

    @classmethod
    def get_product_by_id(cls, id: int) -> 'Product':
        return cls.query.filter_by(id=id).first()

    @classmethod
    def get_promotional_products(cls) -> list['Product']:
        return cls.query.filter_by(promotion=True).all()

    @classmethod
    def get_products_by_category_id(cls, category_id: int) -> list['Product']:
        return cls.query.filter_by(category=category_id).all()

    @classmethod
    # todo: test if it's insensitive
    def search_products_by_string(cls, search_string: str) -> list['Product']:
        return cls.query.filter(cls.name.contains(search_string) | cls.description.contains(search_string)).all()
```

I'm aiming to define new attributes within the `Product` class. I've attempted adding `super().__init__()` after the definition of new attributes, experimented with variables without `self` prefix, and created class variables outside of `__init__`. None provided desired outcome. `super().test = 'test'` resulted in an error indicating `test` doesn't exist in `BaseProduct`. Also with removing `super().__init__` the issue persisted.

Comment: Please include the full traceback errors.  What does the code for obtaining the contents of ```products[0]``` look like?

Comment: These database objects are built in a way that doesn't necessarily run `__init__`.  It's possible to have computed columns, but it's not easy.  I suggest you search for "computed columns" and "views".